# How to use Spark cosmos.oltp datasource/format. Is that configuration a datasource or a format?

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Spark and CosmosDB.
Reviewing the quickstart documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-spark
I found they use "cosmos.oltp" like:

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cosmosCatalog.{}.{} 
using **cosmos.oltp** TBLPROPERTIES(partitionKeyPath = '/id', manualThroughput = '1100')".format(cosmosDatabaseName, cosmosContainerName))
```

The documentation refers to it as a data source but the API suggests it is a format.

What is the purpose of **cosmos.oltp** is it a Datasource or a format?

Comment: Looks like you already asked the exact same question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058283/how-to-use-spark-cosmos-oltp-datasource-format) (which has been closed as off-topic). The issue is that this is really a documentation-request type of question. You haven't shown a specific programming issue. Please don't repost questions if they are closed; consider the reason why they are closed, and create a new question accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon,  That question was closed. I tried to restate the question but they suggested posting a new one since it was closed. I deleted the previous one to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

`cosmos.oltp` is used as `format` when defining Read or Write flows, like:

```
val df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(cfg).load()
df.printSchema()
```

That reads data using the Cosmos DB Connector.

or

```
spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("cat-alive", "Schrodinger cat", 2, true), ("cat-dead", "Schrodinger cat", 2, false)))
  .toDF("id","name","age","isAlive")
   .write
   .format("cosmos.oltp")
   .options(cfg)
   .mode("APPEND")
   .save()
```

That writes data using the Cosmos DB Connector (and you can combine read and write too).

In both cases, they are Datasources, but used through the `format` call with the `cosmos.oltp` name.

The Catalog API support on the other hand is used to create or manage the databases/collections.

The `format` call in your code example is merely to replace the values in `{}`, you could remove the `format` and just have the names as part of the string, or use any other string formatting you choose.

Here are more Spark samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12/Samples

And here are docs for the Catalog API:https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12/docs/catalog-api.md